# Time comparison in python

Tags: python, django, datetime

In a Django website I maintain, I need to check whether users logged in (and performed a certain task) during particular time windows every day. These time windows are fixed and recur daily. For instance, window # 1 is between **3AM** and **6:30AM** (inclusive), whereas window # 2 is **11:50AM** and **2:45P**M (inclusive).

Whenever a user returns to the website, I retrieve `time_now = datetime.datetime.now()`. And since I only care about the time, I use `time_now.time()`. Next, I need to check whether `time_now.time()` falls within any of the aforementioned time windows.

I'm unsure how to make that comparison in python. Particularly, how do I *define* the time objects governing the time windows? Will it be something like:

```
time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = time_now.time()
today3am = now.replace(hour=3, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
today630am = now.replace(hour=6, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0)
if today3am < now < today630am:
    #do something
```

(and likewise for the second time window).

Please advise whether this is the correct way to do it or not. Alternatively, better methods (performance-wise) are also most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to replace the `hour` and `minute` in current time. Because one you have obtained `time()` from `time_now`, you can just compare it with another [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects) object.

```
dt_now = datetime.datetime.now()
t_now = dt_now.time()
```

Now, you need the lower and upper bounds:

```
t_3am = datetime.time(hour=3, minute=0)
t_630am = datetime.time(hour=6, minute=30)
```

Once, you have these you can compare the time objects directly:

```
if t_3am < t_now <= t_630am: # used <= to make the upper bound inclusive
    # do something
```

Performance wise, I would say you should treat `t_3am` and `t_630am` as constants because these are not going to change. So a better way would be to define it only once and not keep replacing the `hour` and `minute` everytime you get current time.

Comment: For some odd reason, doing `datetime.time(hour=3, minute=0)` gives me **descriptor 'time' of 'datetime.datetime' object needs an argument**

Comment: If you do `import datetime` then you can use `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.time`. You will get this error while doing `from datetime import datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments.

1. Yes, this is the correct way to compare datetime objects. The [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) show that datetime objects support arithmetic, multiplicative, and comparative operations.
2. I doubt the example code you provided above is going into production, but your `if` statement is exclusive in that case, not inclusive like you mentioned in your question. I'm also sure you know how to change it to an inclusive if-statement, but I'll include it for others.

   ```
   if today3am <= now <= today630am:
       ## This is true if now is
       ## 03:00 or 03:01
   ```
3. Performance wise, I'm not sure how granular you're looking to get. If logging the time is the only thing you care about, I would suggest using the [time object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects) in the `datetime` module. This will create an object devoid of all date data, making the resulting object take up less RAM, presumably speeding up comparisons. However, I believe the difference between the two approaches will be negligible. I'll leave you to test this out and choose the approach that best supports your goals.

Comment: Thanks for the input Austin.